# Display data from database into a table

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to create very simple table with data from database in it. The table has two rows with three pieces of data in each (three columns).. I was playing around for couple hours now but can't get my head round it..I understand that $row['BandName'] needs to be indexed and increased each time the loop get round, but don't know how to attach index to it. I tried something like this: `$row['BandName'][$i]`  but it displayed only one letter of full name (obviously it's not right)  Any help would be appreciated..

The table looks like this :

```
include 'db_constants.php';
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $host, $cnct);
if( $conn == false )
    {
        echo "Could not connect.\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
else
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM bands";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
if( $stmt === false)
    {
        echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
else
    {
        $recordcount = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );//count the records
        if($recordcount >0)
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        { ?>



           <TR>
    <TABLE border="3" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">

        <?php for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {?>
        <TD align="center" valign="top"> 
            <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
            <tr align="center"> 
                   <td valign="bottom"><a href="details.php" target="_self"><img src="band/1.jpg" width="140" height="110" border="0"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center"> 
        <td class="greytablesm">  <?php echo $row['BandName'];?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </TD>
    <?php }?>
    <TR>
           <?php }
    else {echo "not found";}
    } 
      ?>
```

Table structure is

```
BandID - int autoincrement  
BandName - nvarchar(50)
BandBio - nvarchar(max)
Date   - date



START TABLE <table>
    loop from 1 to 2
       <tr>
          loop from 1 to 2
           <td>
                 Show Details
           </td>
         end loop
       </tr>
    end loop
END TABLE </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally done. and tested

```
    <table border="3" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">

            <?php
            $sql = "select * from deals";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

    if($num_rows > 0)
    {
         $i = 1;
         echo "<tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
        {
    ?>
                <td><?php echo  $row->deal_name ?> </td>
                <?php 
    if( $i++%3 == 0 )
    echo "</tr><tr>";
               }
echo "</tr>";
    }
            ?>
```

Comment: ..No this would create one column. What I need  is  something like:      row1 - |name1|name2|name3|                                                                              row2 - |name4|name5|name6|

Comment: The nearest I can get is row1 - |name1|name1|name1|    row2 - |name2|name2|name2|

Comment: I'm looking for something like thumbnails

Comment: Is it possible to display images or names (or any other data from database) in a table but only in three columns..? Say I have a column in a database that contains names of .... say 6 users and I want to display them all in a table 3 names in first row then other 3 in a next row?

Comment: I have edited now check if it works or make little amendments. it will display 3 per row.

Comment: That's them all in one row now... :(

Comment: I have tested it dear so try to run it somehow.

Comment: I removed all extra code and replaced $row['BandName']  with just 'value'. But still getting 5 'value' in a line...

Answer (score 3):

you want your database data to a table?:

```
<TABLE border="3" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<?php
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //loop through every result set
{ ?>
   <TR>
     <?php foreach($row as $item) { //loop trough every cell in the row  ?>
    <TD><?= $item ?> </TD>
   <?php } ?>
    <TD><?php //you can add none column spefic data here like actions(links) or images ?> </TD>
  <TR>
    <?php 
   }
?>
```

Comment: note, you should not use tables for layout, only for data storage.

Comment: just change your sql-query to get only the 3 columns you want.

Comment: ))) I need three band names in a row, then next row (also three band names).. then its gonna be next page... Something like that.....

Comment: if you show your sql query and database table structure i might help you formulate and sql querry which will work with this code. i dont know what you mean with next page.

Comment: I've updated the code. there's not much difference apart from added sql query etc. I'm trying to create page that would show 6 images with band names under them and at the very bottom navigation bar - something like:   previous_page  current  next_page